# Upsert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, This price definition already exists in this price book: []

Tags: error

guys, anyone would help me to understand with this error? I new in salesforces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you can't put a product with the same currency in a price book more than once. If you're using upsert, you *must* already have the ID of the Price Book Entry, *or* have an External ID field to upsert against. The system will not be able to correctly update the Price Book Entry without a unique identifier, even though this error clearly indicates that it knows there's a duplicate. You will need to either perform a query or add a custom External ID field.

Comment: is there any other option aside of external ID for upsert method?